# CS50 Readability, How to print the total number of letters?

Tags: c, integer, cs50

Hey I've started on the readability problem for cs50 and I'm stuck on step two. I'm sure it's a simple fix but I've already spent an hour or so racking my brain on it to no avail. Basically I just want to print off the total number of letters but when I print off the integer it prints off the entire sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Text:");
    printf("%s\n", s);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }
}
```

which gives me this

```
Text:hello
hello
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Easy way: `int num_letters = printf("%s\n", s); printf("%d\n", num_letters);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you mean `int num_letters = printf("%s\n", s) - 1;`? (the newline ocuppies 1 byte)

Comment: @David Oh, yes. I am not even sure if it needs to be `-2` on windows, since `\n` expands to `\r` `\n` there.

Comment: BTW, universities and colleges may have different course numberings.  So, what is CS50 and what does this have to do with the assignment?  Which university are you attending, so we can look up CS50 and figure out the course work or subject matter.

Comment: BTW, your question title talks about printing integers, yet the content of the question is about counting letters.  Which is correct?  Please edit your post.

Comment: What is the input you gave to your program?  The output doesn't match the behavior of your program.  I would expect `printf("%i\n", i);` to print one number per line, but your question shows the numbers space separated.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That's SO's line wrapping, I fixed it.

Comment: You're not checking whether `s[i]` is a letter. This is counting all the characters, but step 2 requires you to count only letters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews CS50 is a well-known (at least in the US) online course provided by Harvard for all students, and is commonly seen here (it has the mostly unambiguous [tag:cs50] tag)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Text:");

    int length = 0;
    length = strlen(s);

    printf("%i\n", length);
}
```

However, this will take spaces into account as well. Only counting the letters, you have to build for loop to check every single character if it is alphabetic or not. There are built in functions for this. Please do research.